# Is there a way to remove the mongoose.Schema.ObjectId when Im getting an item from mongodb using mongoose?

Tags: node.js

I have two models

Movies.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a title to the movie'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a description']
  },
  video: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a video']
  },
  genre: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
    enum: [
      'Drama',
      'Action',
      'Comedy',
      'Documentary',
    ]
  }
}, {
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
})

MovieSchema.virtual('actors', {
  ref: 'Actor',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'movies.movie',
  justOne: false
})


const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);

export default Movie;
```

and Actor.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const ActorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: [true, 'Please add an actor name']
  },
  born: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a born date']
  },
  bornCountry: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a country']
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add an actor description']
  },
  movies: [{
    _id: false,
    movie: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Movie'
    },
    role: {
      type: String
    }
  }]
})


const Actor = mongoose.model('Actor', ActorSchema);

export default Actor;
```

Thats my controller method to get a single Movie from db

```
const getMovie = async (req, res, next) => {
  const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id).populate('actors', 'name')

  if (!movie) {
    res.status(201).json({ success: false, message: 'Movie not found' })
  }

  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: movie })
}
```

And thats the response

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "genre": [
        "Action"
    ],
    "_id": "603fca3353ffd238484c6fab",
    "title": "Gambito da rainha",
    "description": "Orphaned at the tender age of nine, prodigious introvert Beth Harmon discovers and masters the game of chess in 1960s USA. But child stardom comes at a price.",
    "video": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDrieqwSdgI",
    "__v": 0,
    "actors": [
        {
            "_id": "60400f2e9c782f3d600a93f5",
            "name": "Anya Taylor-Joy",
            "movies": [
                {
                    "movie": "603fca3353ffd238484c6fab"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "id": "603fca3353ffd238484c6fab"
}
```

}

Is there a way to not send back the data.actors.movies.movie id from the response? I tried to select only the name with .populate('actors', 'name'), but im still getting the mongoose.Schema.ObjectId in my response.

Answer (score 0):

Fields referenced through virtual schema are only computed after the query is executed, so they are not reachable during the populate, see [limitations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html).
If you want to unset the property you should use a custom function to exclude it.

Alternative solution is change your Movie schema, including Actor reference:

```js
const MovieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a title to the movie'],
    unique: true,
    trim: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a description']
  },
  video: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a video']
  },
  genre: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
    enum: [
      'Drama',
      'Action',
      'Comedy',
      'Documentary',
    ]
  },
  actors: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Actor' }]
}, {
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
  toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

const Movie = mongoose.model('Movie', MovieSchema);
```

Query:

```js
const movie = await Movie.findById(req.params.id).populate({
    path: 'actors', 
    select: 'name born bornCountry description'
  });
```

Result expected:

```
{
  genre: [ 'Action' ],
  actors: [
    {
      _id: 6040d7c9965dd306b41c7e9e,
      name: 'Anya Taylor-Joy',
      born: 'England',
      bornCountry: 'England',
      description: 'actor'
    }
  ],
  _id: 6040d7c9965dd306b41c7e9d,
  title: 'Gambito da Rainha',
  description: 'Orphaned at the tender age of nine',
  video: 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDrieqwSdgI',
  __v: 1,
  id: '6040d7c9965dd306b41c7e9d'
}
```